# Will or Can iCloud or iTunes back up Apps Documents or App Data

Tags: ios, backup, itunes, icloud

I am developing an iPad App (will not put in App store, just ad-hoc deploy) that would have some documents save at apps Documents folder, and some where I need to enable the iCloud capability for some other function.

If I have no other special configuration (as I don't know), I would like to ask:

1. Will / Can iCloud or iTunes backup the Documents folder and containing files? (I don't want this)
2. What will be backup related to the App? (how about Library Folder)
3. Is iCloud independent per App?
4. If I restore the app to a new device, what will be preserved of not preserved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iCloud will backup the App data. See the [iCloud: iCloud storage and backup overview Support Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12519?viewlocale=en_US), but you turn off the App data backup on a per app basis. See the [iCloud: Select which iOS apps to back up Support Document](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH12791).

Basically the way that a backup and restore will work is iCloud will restore the App data, then will download the application from the iTunes Store (I'm not sure how this will work with an ad-hoc app.) Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I always see from apple and people taking App data, what is app data contains?

Comment: App data would be the app’s sandbox directory I believe. Read up on the Apple Developer site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/Introduction.html

Comment: I find this link and it is very clear for explaining what will be backuped by iCloud and iTunes of the App's sandbox.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTuning/PerformanceTuning.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH8-SW9

Comment: looks like @daniel 's link is outdated - it redirects to UIKit